# PHP background process (create a manager process running on server).

Tags: php, process, background, signals, posix

I have a web page with a button, when I click the button I want it to post data to a php file - I'm fine with this bit. The problem is that I want that PHP file to then start a process on the server unrelated to the httpd, so if I close the web page that PHP script will still be running to the end (Its a long running script).

The long running script does various tasks that take a while, it will be writing the progress to a .json file. I have my JavaScript setup on the webpage to read the progress every second and update the progress bars etc... I want it so that even if I close the web page the script will still be running to the end, this way I can come back whenever and check on the progress etc.

I've been reading around and found mostly people are saying to use exec but that isn't working for me (although I am testing on windows under wamp, maybe that is why?)

I have been told that I should either by using a manager process running on the server (not through apache) or to use POSIX signals. I'm not to sure on any of these so any help would be appreciated, be it explanation, code or links to good articles

I'd like the keep the script setup how it is if possible, so I only need to figure out how to start a background process not on the httpd.

I thank you all in advance,

Ben

Comment: you use different commands to spawn a background process on windows vs linux, so search for the right commands. A dedicated process that runs as a daemon is ideal, but, it may be a bit ambitious for you if your having trouble using exec(). as always when coding and debugging, start simple(launch a hello world script).

Answer (score 0):

I found this suggestion in a [comment](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329) on PHP website.

```
pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
```